# python number variables won't act like they need to

Tags: python

When I use variables print(f) = 0.0 and when I enter it by hand print(x) = 0.004285714285714276 which is what I want my variables to do. How do I get my variables to work like i need to?

```
pad = 109 / 100 + 1.0
dod = 100 / 119 + 1.0

per1 = 1.0 / pad * 100
per2 = 1.0 / dod * 100


b = pad - 1.0
p = per1/100
q = 1.0 - per1/100
f = (b * p - q)/b
print(f)
x = (0.84*0.54-0.45)/0.84
print(x)
```

Comment: Did it not occur you to print out your intermedia variables?  You're apparently using Python 2.x, in which case `/` performs integer division when given two integer operands.  Specifically, `109 / 100` is being evaluated as zero, you'd have to write `109 / 100.0` or something similar to force floating-point division.

Comment: I am using python 3.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the math b*p equals to q

```py
pad = 109 / 100 + 1.0
dod = 100 / 119 + 1.0

per1 = 1.0 / pad * 100
per2 = 1.0 / dod * 100


b = pad - 1.0
p = per1/100
q = 1.0 - per1/100
f = (b * p - q)/b
print(f'b*p:{b*p},q:{q}')
# b*p:0.5215311004784688,q:0.5215311004784688
x = (0.84*0.54-0.45)/0.84
print(x)
```

Comment: forgot to round after each iteration my bad, haha thanks!